# Can $S^n$ be defined without reference to an $n+1$ dimensional embedding space?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

It seems like the most common definition is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ which are unit length. Is this a necessary definition?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense unless you say what kind of mathematical properties of $S^n$ you are interested in. Are you interested in it as: a topological manifold? a smooth manifold? the boundary of a convex body in a linear space? an algebraic variety? Or what?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want something homeomorphic to $S^n$, you can use the one-point compactification of an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Up to homeomorphism, $S^n$ is a triangulated space whose gluing data is that of the $n+1$-dimensional simplex, but with the highest-dimensional simplex removed. (So, for example, you can deform a tetrahedron to a sphere after you remove the stipulation that it has to stay in the shape of a tetrahedron.)

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 2$ it is the unique (up to homeomorphism) compact, simply connected Riemannian manifold which is strictly $1/4$-pinched (Berger, Klingenberg). 
Brendle and Schoen even proved a stronger result: a compact, simply connected manifold $M$ whose sectional
curvatures all lie in the interval $(1, 4]$ is necessarily diffeomorphic to
the sphere $S^n$, see their paper [Manifolds with 1/4-pinched Curvature are Space Forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0766).

Comment: That sounds impressive, but $S^1$ isn't simply connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in topology, then you can naturally construct the spheres inductively with no reference to any embedding. You have to believe that suspension is a natural operation, though. But it is.

Then $S^0$ is a discrete space with two points, and $S^{n+1}$ is the suspension of $S^n$.

If you are only interested in homotopy, then the spheres appear spontaneously a whole lot ; for instance, $S^n$ is the (pointed) space that represents the functor $\pi_n$ (though it may take a little leap of faith to really believe that the homotopy groups are interesting without knowing beforehand their relation with spheres, but you can indeed make a very strong case for that).